# sed replace html

Tags: regex, vim, sed

Having difficulty getting a sed search and replace working with an html file.

I have multiple sections that look like this:

```
<TABLE class="cattable">   
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
      <TH colspan="2">Header</TH></TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Random Amount of Data</TD>
      <TD>3</TD></TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Moar Data</TD>
      <TD>3</TD></TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Yup, More</TD>
      <TD>4</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

I need to:

replace with xxxxFOOxxxx:

```
<TABLE class="cattable">
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
     <TH colspan="2">
```

keep this:

```
Header
```

Replace this with yyyyFOOyyyy:

```
</TH></TR>
```

Keep this:

```
<TR>
   <TD>Random Amount of Data</TD>
   <TD>3</TD></TR>
<TR>
   <TD>Moar Data</TD>
   <TD>3</TD></TR>
<TR>
   <TD>Yup, More</TD>
   <TD>4</TD></TR>
```

replace this with zzzzFOOzzzz:

```
</TBODY></TABLE>
```

Heres what I’ve tried in vim, but cant limit the greedy .* properly:

```
s:\(<TABLE class="cattable">\_s\s*<TBODY>\_s\s*<TR>\_s\s*<TH colspan="2">\)\(.*\)\(<\/TH><\/TR>\)\(\_.*[^<]*\)\(<\/TABLE>\):xxxxFOOxxxx\2yyyyFOOyyyy\4zzzzFOOzzz<br>:g
```

tia

Comment: Regex is not a good choice of tools for this task. Also, vim does not use the standard lazy/greedy regex syntax.

Comment: use one of the many good perl packages to deal with xml. Otherwise, if you insist on using a regexp, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1841533 ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `*` with `\{-}` to get non-greedy match (same as `*?` in PCRE/Perl regexes). For more complicated cases you will have to use something with negative look-aheads/look-behinds: like `\(\(<\/TH><\/TR>\)\@!.\)*` in place of `.*`, here `.\{-}` is probably enough.

Note: won’t work in `sed`.

Note 2: `vim` is not using BRE or ERE (basic/extended regular expressions) like `sed` does, `vim` `:s` is not invoking any external programs (including `sed`) and neither your attempt is suitable for `sed`. Thus if you did not mean to ask how to do this in `sed` remove `sed` from tags.

Comment: Thanks this helped.  I was wanting to use sed because I wasnt having luck in vim.  The vim code was just for reference about what I was trying to do.  I do see the wisdom in what jahroy and Olivier say, and have moved on to python an beautifulsoup.